# Zend Framework, posting comment with ajax and jquery

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

I have been reading up on using Ajax and Jquery with Zend but I can not seem to get the idea down. For example I have a simple post with some comments, I wish to post a comment to the page without the need to refresh.

Here is what I have:

```
 //Controller


 public function viewAction()
{
   // action body
    $postid = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
    $post = new Application_Model_DbTable_Videos(); 
    $this->view->post = $post->getVideos($postid);
    $commentsObj = new Application_Model_DbTable_Comments();
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $commentsForm = new Application_Form_Comments();
    /*
     * Check the comment form has been posted
     */
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($commentsForm->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            $model = new Application_Model_DbTable_Comments();
            $model->saveComments($commentsForm->getValues());
            $commentsForm->reset();
        }
    }
    $data = array( 'id'=> $postid );
    $commentsForm->populate( $data );
    $this->view->commentsForm = $commentsForm;
    $comments = $commentsObj->getComments($postid);
    $this->view->comments = $comments;
    $this->view->edit = '/videos/edit/id/'.$postid;
}
```

---

```
//View

    <?php echo $this->post['Title']; ?><br>
   <?php echo $this->post['Description'];  ?><br><br>

<?php if( count($this->comments) ) : ?>
    <?php foreach( $this->comments as $comment ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $comment['Webpage']; ?>" ><?php echo $this->escape( $comment['Name'] ); ?></a> on <span>
        <?php echo $this->escape( date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime($comment['Postedon']) ) ); ?></span><br><br>
        <?php echo $this->escape( $comment['Description'] ); ?><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<div>No comments</div><br>
<?php endif; ?>
    <br>
    <?php echo $this->commentsForm; ?>
```

Please guide me in some sort of direction because I have spent many hours with no luck :(

Update with my attempt:

```
//View file
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('submitbutton').click(function(){
          var comments = $('comment').val();
         $.ajax({
         url : 'localhost/kiwi/public/videos/addcomment',
         type : 'POST',
         data : {'commments_post':comments },
         success:function(msg){ 
             if(msg=='Ok'){
             alert('You have saved the comment with out refresh');
               }else{
             alert('cant save');
               }
         },
         error:function()
         {
             alert('Error');
         }
      });
});
});
</script>

<?php echo $this->post['Title']; ?><br>
<?php echo $this->post['Description'];  ?><br><br>

<?php if( count($this->comments) ) : ?>
    <?php foreach( $this->comments as $comment ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $comment['Webpage']; ?>" ><?php echo $this->escape( $comment['Name'] ); ?></a> on <span>
        <?php echo $this->escape( date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime($comment['Postedon']) ) ); ?></span><br><br>
        <?php echo $this->escape( $comment['Description'] ); ?><br>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else : ?>
<div>No comments</div><br>
<?php endif; ?>
<br>
<?php echo $this->commentsForm; ?>
```

And my controller:

```
 public function viewAction()
{
   // action body
    $postid = $this->_getParam('id', 0);
    $post = new Application_Model_DbTable_Videos(); 
    $this->view->post = $post->getVideos($postid);
    $commentsObj = new Application_Model_DbTable_Comments();
    $commentsForm = new Application_Form_Comments();

    $data = array( 'id'=> $postid );
    $commentsForm->populate( $data );
    $this->view->commentsForm = $commentsForm;
    $comments = $commentsObj->getComments($postid);
    $this->view->comments = $comments;
}

public function addcommentAction()
{

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $commentsForm = new Application_Form_Comments();
    $commentsObj = new Application_Model_DbTable_Comments();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($commentsForm->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            $model = new Application_Model_DbTable_Comments();
            $model->saveComments($commentsForm->getValues());
            $commentsForm->reset();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Where's the javascript you have tried?

Comment: I have edited my post with my attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this,

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#your_comment_save_button_id').click(function(){
              var comments = $('#commentbox_id').val();
             $.ajax({
             url : 'Your comment save page url',
             type : 'POST',
             data : {'commments_post':comments },
             success:function(msg){ //msg a variable echoed from the save page
                 if(msg=='Ok'){
                 alert('You have saved the comment with out refresh');
                   }else{
                 alert('cant save');
                   }
             },
             error:function()
             {
                 alert('Error');
             }
          });
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The view action should not contain the methods to add a comment. Rather make an `addcoment` action. The Form then contains the ID for the news or whatever plus the comment. You sent the form via ajax and due to `$this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()` you can check if the post comes from a ajax or manual add witihout javascript.

Depending upon which you return a json callback of success and error. You don't only give back a 'success' but you can give back the comment added within the json, too.

jQuery handles the rest. Propperly format the comment, add it to your DOM and viola. Comment added.

As a little Guidance this should be enough, if u want specific information for any of the above mentioned, hit me a comment, ill further edit my answer then ;)

Comment: Ok so I have to make a new action in my controller that will process my form, which I somewhat get. Now the part I don't understand, how am I going to render this action in my View actions view file?

Also to be clear how would I even send back the contents of my comments form to such action?

Comment: Well, @ubercooluk did tell you how to post something via ajax. You bind the ajax-call to your submit-click and sent the data of your form to some url like "project.tld/addcomment". addcomment then does simply add the comment to the database. Further, IF it was an ajax-call (see answer) it returns some json (google zend return json) - the rendering of the comments is primarily done from your "view" action of the news, just like u do now. To refresh after a new comment, simply "manually" add it, or make another action that returns only the comments for a news and replace current with callback :)

Comment: Ok so I tried the code from @ubercooluk and I also made a new action to add comment but am not even close. Please tell me where I need to improve my code. Thank you so much for you help so far!!! Oh by the way I updated my code above.